# driver.send_keys("Selenium") AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to input text in google textbox. Suddenly got this error. Is something modified/changed in selenium newly?
Code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located(By.NAME, "gLFyf")
    )
finally:
    driver.send_keys("Selenium")
```

error:

```
  File "C:\Users\bhatt\OneDrive\Desktop\Sublime\gotta_master_selenium.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.send_keys("Selenium")
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

I also have some more errors

````
```EC.presence_of_element_located(By.NAME, "gLFyf")TypeError: presence_of_element_located() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
````

I've been looking for solution throughout the vacation. Still can't figure out the solution

Answer (score 1):

For first error:

You have to use `send_keys()` function with webelement not with webdriver.

Syntax:

```
driver.find_element(<locator type like By.XPATH or By.ID or...>, <locator value>).send_keys("<value to enter>")
```

For second error:

You have to use one more parenthesis '()' in the below line:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, "gLFyf")))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not send text `send_keys("Selenium")` to a web driver object `driver`.
Text should be sent to a specific web element you need to locate with the `driver`